# php missing argument error for a function

Tags: php

hi guys i am Currently Confused why do i get this error about missing argument when i compile the code it gives me this error Warning: Missing argument 5 for print_LCS(), here is my code:

this is the function

```
function print_LCS($b,$x,$i,$j,$k){
    $fLCS=array();

    if ($i==0||$j==0) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if ($b[$i][$j]=='c')
    {
        print_LCS($b,$x,$i-1,$j-1);
        $fLCS[$k] = $x[$i-1]." ";
        $k++;


    }
    elseif ($b[$i][$j]=='u') 
    {
        print_LCS($b,$x,$i-1,$j);
    }
    else
    {
        print_LCS($b,$x,$i,$j-1);
    }
    return array($fLCS);
}
```

and this is the function call:

```
list($final)=print_LCS($var2,$first,$var3,$var4,$var5);
```

hoping for your quick response guys. thank you So much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the nested calls to the same function ( presumably for recursion ) as it only has 4 values passed to it.

```
function print_LCS($b,$x,$i,$j,$k){
    $fLCS=array();

    if ($i==0||$j==0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if ($b[$i][$j]=='c'){
        print_LCS($b,$x,$i-1,$j-1, $XXXXX );/* you need another parameter here or a default value */
        $fLCS[$k] = $x[$i-1]." ";
        $k++;


    } elseif ($b[$i][$j]=='u') {
        print_LCS($b,$x,$i-1,$j,$XXXXX);/* you need another parameter here or a default value */
    } else {
        print_LCS($b,$x,$i,$j-1,$XXXXX);/* you need another parameter here or a default value */
    }
    return array($fLCS);
}
```

Not knowing what the funtion is doing it is hard to say whether this might work or cause more issues but you could supply the fifth parameter with a default value in the initial declaration, like:

```
function print_LCS($b,$x,$i,$j,$k=false){/* rest of function */}
```

That way it would happily continue at the points it failed - though what the 5th parameter brings to the table is unknown.

Comment: thank you very much the error was solved but the function is still not working properly i want to use the $k variable to function as a counter to the index of the array $fLCS to save the value coming from $x[$i-1] and return it but the problem is that the counter wont move it only returns the value in the [0] index. how could i fix that. thanks for the help

Comment: I don't know as I don't understand what the function is doing, no idea what values are being passed in initially nor what the expected output is.

Comment: okay sir thank you for the time in helping me, at least i know the reason for missing arguments. by the way the function is printing the longest common sub-sequence of the given two sequences of words.